# Nonstandard definition for the generator of a standard Ito diffusion

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

For a standard Brownian motion, the generator of the diffusion is
$$
 L = \frac12 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}.
$$

Is there a nonstandard definition of this generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try F. Herzberg at http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-33149-7_7